Printing 4 cells from every row
I have the following datatable:



rowNR
L1
L2
L3
L4




row1
Listing1
Listing2
Listing3
Listing4


row2
Listing1
Listing2
Listing3
Listing4


row3
Listing1
Listing2
Listing3
Listing4


row4
Listing1
Listing2
Listing3
Listing4


row5
Listing1
Listing2
Listing3
Listing4



I would like to print every "Listing" cell from every row to a new page.
ex: page 1 - Listing1(row1), page2 - Listing2(row1)...so in the above example I will need 20 pages.
**The problem is: ** The page number goes to infinite and never stops.
My code looks like this:
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            var doc = sender as PrintDocument;
            var curX = e.MarginBounds.X + 11;
            var curY = e.MarginBounds.Y + 11;
            Pen pen = new Pen(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFBD2D"), 1f);
            int checkedrows = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            using (var fontNormal = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8))
            using (var sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                sf.Alignment = sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                int itemHeight = (int)fontNormal.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + 1;

                for (int row = x; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    for (int j = y; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (x != row || y != j)
                        {
                            x = row;
                            y = j;
                            e.HasMorePages = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ("Listing1" == dt.Columns[j].ColumnName || "Listing2" == dt.Columns[j].ColumnName || "Listing3" == dt.Columns[j].ColumnName || "Listing4" == dt.Columns[j].ColumnName)
                            {
                                if (dt.Rows[row][j].ToString() == "")
                                    continue;

                                var imgRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 160);
                                var labelRect = new Rectangle(
                                    imgRect.Right,
                                    imgRect.Bottom,
                                    imgRect.Width,
                                    itemHeight);

                                using (var qrImage = Utils.QRCode.GenerateQRCODE(dt.Rows[row][j].ToString()))
                                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(qrImage, imgRect);

                                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX, curY + 139);//|<left
                                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY + 139, curX + 196, curY + 139);// _bottom
                                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX + 196, curY + 139, curX + 196, curY);// >|right
                                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX + 196, curY);// -up

                                e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(dt.Rows[row][j].ToString(),
                                     fontNormal, Brushes.Black,
                                     labelRect, sf);
                                e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
                                //curX = imgRect.Right; //+ 30

                                e.HasMorePages = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            refreshprintbtn.Enabled = true;
            groupBox1.Text = "QR CODE | Codes: " + checkedrows + " / " + sum;
        }

Edit (04.12.2024) - It works fine, except it does not skip the white pages (dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() empty values):
private int x = 0;
private int y = 26;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = sender as PrintDocument;
    var curX = e.MarginBounds.X + 11;
    var curY = e.MarginBounds.Y + 11;
    //bool toprint = true;

    if ("Listare1" == dt.Columns[y].ColumnName || "Listare2" == dt.Columns[y].ColumnName || "Listare3" == dt.Columns[y].ColumnName || "Listare4" == dt.Columns[y].ColumnName)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() != "")
        {
            using (var pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFBD2D")))
            using (var fontNormal = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX, curY + 139);//|<left
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY + 139, curX + 196, curY + 139);// _bottom
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX + 196, curY + 139, curX + 196, curY);// >|right
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, curX, curY, curX + 196, curY);// -up

                var imgRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 160);
                using (var qrImage = Utils.QRCode.GenerateQRCODE(dt.Rows[x][y].ToString()))
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(qrImage, imgRect);//RotateImage(qrImage, -90), imgRect);
            }
        }
    }

    if (y < 51)
    {
        y = y + 9;
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        y = 26;
        x++;
    }
    if (x < dt.Rows.Count)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    refreshprintbtn.Enabled = true;
    // groupBox1.Text = "QR CODE | Codes: " + checkedrows + " / " + sum;
}


Tip: Get rid of the nested loops. Start the printing with x = 0 and y = 1, get the value of that field (row -> x, column -> y) from the data table and print it. Increase y by 1 and request a new page if y < dt.Columns.Count - 1 OR reset y to 1, increase x by 1. If x < Rows.Count then request a new page, otherwise break.

What "page number" are you referring to?  In the code shown, when using a debugger, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Please see: How do I avoid misusing tags?

@dr.null Now, the code works file (added code above - Edit (04.12.2024) ), except it does not skip empty values for dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() and creates empty pages. I tried to introduce a bool variable, that at the beginning is true and changes on both if's else statements to false...and if true set e.HasMorePages = true; , but is not working.  Note: My starting columns index is at 26 and last Listing4 index is 50 (Listing1 - 26, Listing2 - 34, Listing3 - 42, Listing4 - 50)

Replace the if (x < dt.Rows.Count) { } block with a loop. for (; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++) { if (dt.Rows[x][y]?.ToString() != "") { e.HasMorePages = true; break; } }.

thanks all for the help...its working
